# an incomplete ussd code sometimes follows by connection error or invalid mmi code

Tags: android

I have written a simple android app with only one button which runs the following ussd comand

*111*241#

After pressing the button for the first time the ussd dialog appears and asks for the input. If I cancel the input dialog and press the button again then usually (NOT ALWAYS) I encounter this error: connection problem or invalid mmi code.

If I wait for a few seconds and press the button for the second time then everything is fine and I see no error.

Hence, I guess there shoud be a cache for ussd commands and it needs to be cleared. Or may be another solution to prevent error on successive call to the incompleted ussd commands.